# Rearrange elements in an integer array in a fashion where-you first replace and then move the replaced integer to first part of the array

Tags: java, arrays

I came across a Hackerearth coding problem where you have to perform the following tasks over an integer array-

1. Search for a particular number in the array and replace it's occurrences with 1
2. Move all the 1s to the first part of the array, maintaining the original order of the array

***For example-*** if we have an integer array `{22,1,34,22,16,22,35,1}`, here we search for the number "22" (*let us assume it is present in the array*), replace it with 1 and move all those 1s (*including the 1s already present*) to the first part of the array and the resultant array should look like `{1,1,1,1,1,1,34,16,35}` -*maintaining the original order of the array*, preferably in **Java**.
I actually *****have coded a solution and it works fine but is not optimal*****, ***can anyone help me find an optimal solution (w.r.t. time-space complexity)?***

---

Below is my solution-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] n = rearr(new int[] {22,1,34,22,16,22,1,34,1}, 22);
    for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(n[i]+" ");
    }
}
static int[] rearr(int[] a, int x) {
    
    int[] temp = new int[a.length];
    int j=0, c=0, k=0;
    //search and replace
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == x) {
            a[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    //shift all 1s to first part of array or shift all non-1s to last part of the array
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] != 1) {
            temp[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
        if(a[i] == 1) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length && c>0; i++, c--) {
        a[i] = 1;
        j++;
    }
    for(int i=j ;i<a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = temp[k];
        k++;
    }
    
    return a; 
}
```

Comment: You should only need to iterate over the source array twice.  Once to write enough 1's into the destination array, and once to write in all the other values.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in linear time and space complexity, by returning a completely new list instead of modifying the original list.

```
static int[] rearr(int[] a, int x) {
    // allocate the array we'll return
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    int fillvalue = 1;
    // iterate backwards through the list, and transplant every value OTHER than
    // (x or 1) to the last open index in b, which we track with b_idx
    int b_idx = b.length - 1;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (a[i] != x && a[i] != fillvalue)) {
            b[b_idx] = a[i];
            b_idx--;
        }
    }
    // once we've gone through and done that, fill what remains of b with ones
    // which are either original or are replacements, we don't care
    for (int i = b_idx; i >= 0; i--) {
        b[i] = fillvalue;
    }
    return b;
}
```

This is linear space complexity because it requires additional space equal to the size of the given list. It's linear time complexity because, in the worst case, it iterates over the size of the list exactly twice.

As a bonus, if we decide we want to leave the original `1`s where they were, we can do that without any trouble at all, by simply modifying the `if` condition. Same if we decide we want to change the fill value to something else.

Doing this with constant space complexity would require `O(n^2)` list complexity, as it would require swapping elements in `a` to their proper positions. The easiest way to do that would probably be to do replacements on a first run through the list, and then do something like bubblesort to move all the `1`s to the front.

Comment: Thanks. Both the solutions work. I would prefer this one as this was my approach as well to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single iteration through the array. We can use 2 pointer approach here where we will use on pointer to iterate through the array and other one to point to the index of 1 in the array.

### The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // input array
    int[] arr = { 22, 1, 34, 22, 16, 22, 35, 1, 20, 33, 136 };
    // element to be replaced
    int x = 22;

    int j = -1;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == x) {
            if (j == -1) {
                j = i;
            }
            // incase arr[i]==x
            arr[i] = 1;
        } else {
            if (j != -1) {
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = 1;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

---

Here we initialise j=-1 since we consider there are no 1's present in the array.
Then we start iterating the array from the end towards the starting of the array as we have to push all the 1's to the starting of the array. Now when we reach to 1 or x (particular number in your case), we check if this is first occurrence of the x or 1, if yes then we initialise the j with this index and change arr[i] = 1 because this could be equal to x then we need to make it 1. If the arr[i] is not 1 or x it means its a number which we need to push at back of the array. We check if we have position of 1 or j=-1. If j=-1 it means this number is already pushed back at end of array else we swap the number at i and j, and decrement j by 1.

At the end of the array we will have the array sorted in a fashion which is required.

Time Complexity: Since we are only iterating the array one, hence the time complexity is O(n).
Space Complexity: Since there are no extra space being used or constant space being used hence the space complexity is O(1)